# Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Now I am super-confused. Our web site has had jQuery accordions on it for a year now without any trouble. It was working fine up to a day or so ago. Then, without any changes made from our end, the accordions are no longer functioning in IE11 and the latest Firefox.  The latest Chrome and Safari appear to display the site correctly, however. Almost every page of our site uses accordions; here's one of them:

http://www.americanaccents.com/napkin-color-tradition.html

Running the F12 Developer Tools in IE, I see the message "Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'." The offending lines of code (specifically, the third line) are:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#Accordion1" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      autoHeight: false
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Any idea what's going on here? This is a priority problem, but I don't know where else to turn.

Answer (score 3):

I find it hard to believe that this has happened "without any changes made from [your] end."

[image: your head tag]

You have loaded jQuery a total of three times. Two of the three come after you load your jQuery accordion. All of them come after the SpryAccordion. When a plugin like `jquery.ui.accordion` is loaded, it attaches itself to the jQuery object - `$`. When you load another jQuery script, `$` is reset to an instance of that script, eliminating the plugin.

If this has been unchanged, it's almost entirely improbable this ever worked. Someone has added two jQuery fetches (among other duplicated things) at the end of your `head`. If this content is coming from 3rd party services, you should do everything in your power to eliminate these remote dependencies. Pulling code like that into your site dynamically is very dangerous, as you can see it's now breaking your site.

**Remove all of the duplicated jQuery, or make sure your accordion plugin is loaded after the last one.**

By the way, questions should [duplicate the problem in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) content. I've created a screenshot to make this question useful in the longer term for other people, but it's still a poor piece of content overall. No one searching for help in the future should have to go to your website to understand the problem.

Comment: There are also two different versions of the jQueryUI accordion plugin loaded ?!

Comment: @Starscream1984 I'm not seeing the second one, but could you perhaps be seeing the `.css` loaded first, and then the `.js` loaded later?

Comment: I have a longer answer at the bottom, Its not the accordion loaded twice but the jQuery Library itself. You are overwriting the jQuery UI attachments, hence making .accordion undefined.

Comment: Oh yes, one is css :) I'll let them off that one.

Comment: Also *shouldn't* be mixing styles and scripts, load all styles, then all scripts to allow the browser to load in parallel.

Comment: Wow. Okay, let me address everything one comment at a time. A whole lot of assumptions are being made--some correct, some incorrect--that I feel the need to clear things up a bit.

Comment: Firstly, @rockerest, I swear on my father's grave that I have **not** touched our web site in over a month. Nothing. And I rather resent your implication that I was lying to cover my ass. If I screw something up, I own up to it. (See one of my further comments below.)

Comment: Second: I see that there are, indeed, two sections of Javascript code near the end of each file that are exactly duplicated. This is, indeed, my fault. It is where I mistakenly forgot to remove the extra piece when I chose to move it to the Dreamweaver template file. My mistake. That takes care of one of the three jQuery loads.

Comment: Third: I never explicitly called jQuery more than once. (Actually, I never explicitly called it at all; I just let Dreamweaver put it in automatically for me. But I digress.) The first call, near the top of the code, was placed by me via Dreamweaver's tools. (I know it's bad form to put javascript code at the beginning, but that's what DW did, so I figured there was a good reason for it.)  continuing...

Comment: The second (and third) calls to load jQuery were **NOT** done by me. They are done inside of a third-party plug-in from vds.sage.net. I was completely unaware that their tool was *also* loading jQuery. I merely followed their step-by-step instructions on how to put the tool on our site. (It's the Virtual Design Studio tool, btw.)  
  
Because I am now aware of this, do I need to make sure that the VDS plug-in is loaded *before* the function call to `$( "#Accordion1" ).accordion()`?

Comment: (( Last comment regarding the fact that I haven't touched our site in over a month: It is *entirely* possible that a recent browser update to IE and Firefox have caused them to be more strict regarding Javascript code. In fact, I see that IE just installed a security update a few days ago. It's also entirely possible that the VDS plug-in was updated without my knowledge which caused this problem. Just some food for thought. ))

Comment: I get the same error in latest Chrome as well

Comment: Oh, and regarding the last paragraph, @rockerest, I am so very glad that you went out of your way to point out how the site is a 'poor piece of content' to someone who had to step in on an emergency basis after the main site creator left suddenly and was given only 48 hours to update it. I guess it may have been wrong for me to show you the site where the problem actually exists, since that's way faster than creating an example piece of HTML just for stackoverflow. After all, it's only my future with this company that's at stake with this problem.

Comment: And after all of that, moving the the script which calls `.accordion()` all the way to the end, after **everything** else, I still get the same error.

Comment: @sturm I "went out of my way" because instead of answering the question, it's ripe for outright closure. Instead of closing, I answered, and included the reason it would have been closed for. SO is not a personal help service, that would not be free. SO is for creating knowledge that helps everyone. If you feel that SO should help you keep a company afloat, you should seriously reconsider the long-term viability of the business. Finally: moving the call to `.accordion` to the end is irrelevant. The problem is that jQuery is loaded a 2nd and 3rd time after the accordion plugin, overwriting it.

Comment: Fine, then, just close the damn question. Or, never mind, I'll just delete it here in a bit.

Comment: Oh, and I guess you might as well just delete my account here as well, since I'm apparently mis-using the site.

Comment: @sturm You're acting like a child. I've explained very calmly why the question is inappropriate. I linked to the site's rules. You have the opportunity to adapt and improve. This is the lifeblood of development. *This is professional behavior.* If you choose to leave, that's fine. But anyone who would like to contribute to a knowledge-base greater than any individual is welcome to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

You have : 
jQuery Library Version : jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014

You are using the accordion library : accordion version:"1.10.4"
1.10.4(Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)

You are loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

two times.

and this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vds.sage.net/pluginsupport/highslide/highslide-full.packed.js"></script>
```

two times and some other stuff.

You load the jQuery accordion after you make a request for

```
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

BUT!! You then reload the jQuery library two more times. You are overwriting the already extended jQuery object and there for removing the jQuery UI accordion and other jQuery UI goodness that is inside your

```
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

ALSO : 
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/
They urge you to upgrade. - Not always a good idea in large scale apps, seems 1.9 of jQuery has some breaking changes.

Hope this helps..

Take away :
clean up your HTTP Requests for Scripts and this should fix your problem

Comment: Thank you, @Wes. Please see my comments in the above answer for responses to your assumptions. Also, aren't 1.10 and 1.11 newer than 1.9? And where do you see that I'm using 1.9 in my site explicitly? (( Perhaps SAGE might be using 1.9 for the VDS plug-in, but that's entirely out of my control. )) And finally, all jQuery versions you see there were added by Dreamweaver's utilities (not something I had control over). I guess one of the takeaways from today is to never trust Dreamweaver's jQuery.